# Storing functions in a HashMap

Tags: scala

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do in the code below:

```
class Foo extends SomeClass
class Bar extends SomeClass
def f[A<:SomeClass,B<:SomeClass](a:A,b:B):B = b
val a = new Foo
val b = new Bar

scala> Map[String,(_<:SomeClass)=>(_<:SomeClass)]("key"->f(a,b))
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Bar
 required: Function2[_ <: SomeClass, _ <: SomeClass, _ <: SomeClass]
              Map[String,(_<:SomeClass,_<:SomeClass)=>(_<:SomeClass)]("key"->fun(a, b))
                                                                            ^
```

Comment: Why don't you just pattern match over argument and choose proper function? It will be [likely] faster and much more maintainable. By the way right now you are trying to store **result** of function, not function itself

Comment: I feel like I still don't understand the capabilities of Scala's type system that well. Could you may be give an example?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues:

1. `f(a,b)` is the applied function `f` and you'll hence put the return value, not the function itself.
2. Scala does not support first order polymorphic function values (use Shapeless, if you really need them), so try to use non-generics first.
3. As @GarrettHall stated, your map has the wrong type.

Proposed solution:

```
def f(a: SomeClass,b: SomeClass): SomeClass = b

Map[String, (SomeClass, SomeClass) => SomeClass](key -> (f _))
```

Note also @om-nom-nom's comment, that pattern matching over `key` might be faster depending on what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Your signature for the `Map` is wrong.  It should be:

```
  Map[String,(_<:SomeClass, _<:SomeClass)=> (_<:SomeClass)]("key" -> f)
```